# Autocomplete bash function with available system font

Tags: bash, autocomplete, fonts

I have a function. How can I add to it an auto-completion with an available font name?

So if I type something like `doSomethingWithFont Ubun<tab>` it'll be completed to `doSomethingWithFont Ubuntu\ Mono` for example.

```
doSomethingWithFont () {
    echo $1
}

_completeWithFontName () {
    # ????
}

complete -F _completeWithFontName doSomethingWithFont
```

Comment: This sounds like two separate questions: (a) How to get a list of the available fonts and (b) how to create tab completion for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the fc_list command to list available fonts, in the format you want them to be entered.

This is how that fits into your sample code:

```
    _completeWithFontName() { < <(fc-list -f "%{family}\n" | grep "^$2" | sort -u) mapfile -t COMPREPLY; }
    complete -F _completeWithFontName doSomethingWithFont
```

Note that you should not pipe into the mapfile command: piping puts the destination command into a subshell, and you would loose the new contents of the COMPREPLY array immediately, on exit of that subshell. Redirecting `<` from a process substitution `<(...)` works better.

The `-f` parameter to fc-list sets the format, the simple grep command selects those font names that match the first characters entered on the command line, and the sort is for convenience. I also add a `-u` (unique) parameter to the sort because in this example I list only the families; each variant would appear as a duplicate, so we should sort them out.

Comment: Thank you. The problem only with spaces in font names. For example I have fonts with names : Samyak Devanagari, Samyak Gujarati, Samyak Malayalam, Samyak Tamil. The tab-completion will stop after the first space.

Comment: That is an issue with all completions. You could, like you would do to match e.g. filenames with spaces in them, enter quoted prefixes, e.g. `"Ubu<tab>`; the complete functionality will handle that just fine, and even add a closing quote as soon as you `<tab>` when your prefix has gotten unique. Without quoting, you can escape spaces: `Ubuntu\ Co<tab>` will complete to `Ubuntu\ Condensed`.

Comment: File names don't have this issue, autocompletion escapes symbols automaticaly. I didn't think about starting argument with doublequote for proper completion, it's interesting.

Comment: I assumed to much. It turns out that to escape spaces with a backslash and have `Ubuntu\ Co<tab>` complete to `Ubuntu\ Condensed`, you would have to make your function handle the backslash as an escape; the complete functionality passes it to your function in $2 as a plain backslash character followed by a space or whatever you entered. That means roughly remove unquoted backslashes, except for the 2nd of `\\\` (if that ever happens in a fontname), and on output again replace spaces with escaped spaces.

Comment: @tehkonst About spaces and filename completion: that may depend on the files present. Try for instance `touch "a file" "afile" "a document"` and then try to complete `ls a<tab>` and `ls a <tab>` (a space after the 'a'). Interesting things happen, that clearly have been programmed to make them happen like that for a reason. Now it's up to you to do the same for your font completion.

Comment: May I ask a question? I'm ok with completion starting with double-quote like `"Ubun<tab>`. But why doesn't it work when I use `nohup` before the command? `nohup doSomethingWithFont "Ubun<tab>` doesn't suggest completion.

Comment: Command completion is linked to the command. Your command is `nohup`, so you would have to define a completion for that as well.